# How to use same SharedPreferences instance when FLUTTER app is on foreground state

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I need to access the app shared preferences to save some data from push notification,

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
```

above won't get the shared preference instance that use in app state. how can I use same shared preferences for all state of the app.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use this package [Flutter Background Service](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_service).

It helps to execute dart code in background.